# FormMethod.Post returning 0

Tags: c#, html, post, entity-framework-6, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a problem with a FormMethod Post, I'm trying to post one single value (id) and store it in a Session variable, but the value return 0.

This is my code.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "ProductSelec", FormMethod.Post))
                    {

                        @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => item.id, new { value = "@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.id)" })

                        <div class="AppOpt">
                            <button type="submit" name="submit" style="background-image: url('../Content/ICONS/SystemApp/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.img)');border-radius: 20px;background-size: cover;background-repeat: no-repeat;" class="AppImg">
                                <div class="OptNameRec">
                                    <div class="OptIcon">
                                        <img src='~/Content/ICONS/@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.icon)'>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.nombre)</p>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear"></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="OptImage"></div>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    }
                }
```

The form is inside the foreach, becuase I'm creating the elements dinamically from a DB.

I want to store the item.id clicked.

This is my Controller

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.aplicaciones.ToList());
    }

    public ActionResult ProductFamily()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public int Index(aplicaciones aplicaciones)
    {
        Session["appID"] = aplicaciones.id;

        return aplicaciones.id;

    }
```

and this is my Model.

```
  public partial class aplicaciones
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public aplicaciones()
    {
        this.appNfam = new HashSet<appNfam>();
    }

    public int id { get; set; }
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    public string icon { get; set; }
    public string img { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<appNfam> appNfam { get; set; }
}
```

I was trying to create another Model, but when I added, the foreach didn't read the values from the database.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why do you have an "@" before `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your controller method to:

```
[HttpPost]
public int Index(int id)
{
    Session["appID"] = id;

    return id;
}
```

Change your Html.BeginForm to be:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ProductSelec", new { id = item.id },FormMethod.Post, new { })
```

You should also be able to remove the hidden field since the ID will be posted by itself from your form action.

Comment: That's exactly what I want, but I have another problem, when I change my Html.BeginForm, something weird happens in my view, after load the buttons, the code add this. System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm
System.Web.Mvc.Html.MvcForm.

Forget it, I solved that, thank you for your answer.

Comment: Remove the @ before Html.BeginForm.   It should read @using (Html.BeginForm....., not using (@Html.BeginForm.....  Updated the original answer.